# setState not resetting state / switching between modals

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-redux

I asked similar question earlier, but didn't get much back. I have two modals for user auth: join and login. Each modal has a link to the other one. Displayed login errors persist when you click on the "sign up" and switch to the join modal and vise versa. I tried to set the state.errors to empty array, but the errors still persist. I changed handleSwitch to callback. The errors array still has length. I tried using switched as part of the state, resetting it to true in handleSwitch and ternary, no result either. Can anybody suggest an alternative solution.

```
import React from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: [],
            switched: false
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleSwitch = this.handleSwitch.bind(this);
        this.mapErrors = this.mapErrors.bind(this);
        this.handleErrors = this.handleErrors.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ errors: this.props.errors})
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prev) {
        if (prev.errors.length !== this.props.errors.length) {
            this.setState( {errors: this.props.errors} )
        }
    }

    handleInput(type) {
        return (err) => {
            this.setState({ [type]: err.currentTarget.value })
        };
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        const user = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        this.props.processForm(user)
            // .then(() => this.props.history.push('/users')); //change to /videos later
    }

    handleSwitch() {
        // debugger
        this.setState({ errors: [] }, function () {
            this.props.openModal('signup')
        });
        // debugger
    }

    mapErrors() {
        if (this.state.errors.length) {
            return this.state.errors.map((error, i) => {
                return <p key={i}>{error}</p>
            })
        }
    }

    handleErrors() {
        debugger
        if (!this.state.switched) {
            return <div className="errors">{this.mapErrors}</div>
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.errors)
        return (
            <div className="login-form">
                <div>
                    <h2 className="login-header">Log in to Foxeo</h2>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <input className="login-email"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        placeholder="Email address"
                        onChange={this.handleInput('email')}
                    />
                    <input className="login-password"
                        type="password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        onChange={this.handleInput('password')}
                    />
                    
                    <div className="errors">{this.mapErrors()}</div>
                
                
                    {/* { this.state.switched ? 
                        <div className="errors">{this.handleErrors()}</div> :
                        <div className="errors">{this.mapErrors()}</div>
                    } */}
            
                    
                    <button className="login-button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Log in with email</button>

                    <div className="login-footer">Don't have an account?
                        {/* <button className="login-form-btn" onClick={() => this.props.openModal('signup')}>Join</button> */}
                        <button className="login-form-btn" onClick={ this.handleSwitch}> Join</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: please provide a  `codesandbox`

Comment: Codebox doesn't work, errors come from ruby backend and openModal is in a different component

Comment: the `errors` on `props` - any chance those are changing?

Comment: they persist and readonly, hence me trying to mutate the state

Comment: @user13790968 Why are you copying redux store values to local state instead of just using the values from redux store (props)? You are not resetting the error in redux store so the error keeps being passed as props.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting the new errors from the props instead of from state:

```
    mapErrors() {
        if (this.props.errors.length) {
            return this.props.errors.map((error, i) => {
                return <p key={i}>{error}</p>
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching resetErrors action solved the issue. The handleSwitch method is quite simple:

```
    handleSwitch() {
        this.props.resetErrors()
        this.props.openModal('signup')
    }
```

session actions:

```
import * as apiUtil from '../util/session_api_util';

export const RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER = 'RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER';
export const LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER = 'LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER';
export const RECEIVE_ERRORS = 'RECEIVE_ERRORS';
export const CLEAR_ERRORS = 'CLEAR_ERRORS';

const receiveErrors = (errors) => ({
    type: RECEIVE_ERRORS,
    errors
})

const clearErrors = () => ({
    type: CLEAR_ERRORS,
    errors: []
})

const receiveCurrentUser = (user) => ({
    type: RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER,
    user
});

const logoutCurrentUser = () => ({
    type: LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER
});


export const signup = user => dispatch => (
    apiUtil.signup(user).then(user => (
        dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(user))
    ), err => (
        dispatch(receiveErrors(err.responseJSON))
    ))
);

export const login = user => dispatch => {
    return apiUtil.login(user).then(user => {
        dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(user))
    }, err => (
        dispatch(receiveErrors(err.responseJSON))
    ))
};

export const logout = () => dispatch => apiUtil.logout()
    .then(() => dispatch(logoutCurrentUser())); 

export const resetErrors = () => dispatch(clearErrors());
```

session errors reducer:

```
import { RECEIVE_ERRORS, RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER, CLEAR_ERRORS } from '../actions/session_actions';


const sessionErrorsReducer = (state = [], action) => { 

    Object.freeze(state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_ERRORS:
            return action.errors; 
        case CLEAR_ERRORS:
            return [];
        case RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER:
            return []; 
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default sessionErrorsReducer;
```